# How to build a controlled and uncontrolled Input component in React at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, controlled-component

I am trying to build a component that can either be used controlled or uncontrolled. Similar to how TextField in [MaterialUI](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled) or Input in [ChakraUI](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/form/input). So the component works with or without the `value` props. What is the best way to build this kind of component?